# Remover conteúdo depois de adicionado em javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou adicionando um motivo, ate aí ok, deleto o primeiro motivo, mas os adicionados não consigo deletar!

```js
var antes = 'Bem estar psicológico <img src="delete.png" style="width: 1cm" onclick="deleteMot(' + '"Bem estar psicológico"' + ');"> <br>';


function addMotivo() {
  var mot = document.getElementById("newMotivo").value;
  if (mot != "") {
    antes = antes + mot + ' <img src="delete.png" style="width: 1cm" onclick="deleteMot("' + mot + '");"> <br>';
    document.getElementById("motivos").innerHTML = antes;
    document.getElementById("newMotivo").value = "";
  } else {
    window.alert("Motivo inválido");
  }
}

function deleteMot(i) {
  if (confirm("Tem a certeza que quer apagar?")) {
    var r = i + ' <img src="delete.png" style="width: 1cm" onclick="deleteMot("' + i + '");"> <br>';
    antes = antes.replace(r, '');
    document.getElementById("motivos").innerHTML = antes;
  }
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="infor" style="clear: both;"><b>Motivos</b></div>
  <div class="infor" style="clear: both; margin-top: 7px;">

    <input type="text" id="newMotivo" placeholder="Ficar atraente">
    <button onclick="addMotivo();" style="width: auto">Adicionar Motivo: </button>

  </div>
  <div class="infor" id="motivos" style="clear: both; margin-top: 7px; color: #CC720E;"><b>Bem estar psicologico</b>
    <img src="delete.png" style="width: 18px" onclick="deleteMot('Bem estar psicológico');" alt="" />
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: obd david pela edição

Comment: nunca use `getElementById` use `getElementsByClassName` aí seria: `document.getElementsByClassName("motivo" +  i)`

Comment: O problema acontece porque você está tentando acessar um identificador que está duplicado, ou triplicado...Ele precisa ser uma class para poder ser multiplicado.

Comment: como faço isso Lollipop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está nas concatenações que você está fazendo, que está causando quebra de string. Você pode usar aspas simples e fazer o escape delas:

**Nesta linha:**

```
var antes = 'Bem estar psicológico <img src="delete.png" style="width: 1cm" onclick="deleteMot(\'Bem estar psicológico\');"> <br>';
```

**Nesta:**

```
antes = antes + mot + ' <img src="delete.png" style="width: 1cm" onclick="deleteMot(\'' + mot + '\');"> <br>';
```

**E nesta:**

```
var r = i + ' <img src="delete.png" style="width: 1cm" onclick="deleteMot(\'' + i + '\');"> <br>';
```

Só que também você está fazendo isso de uma forma terrível, fazendo `replace` de strings. Sugiro usar uma lista criando `id`s de forma dinâmica para cada `<li>`:

```js
var novoid = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('#motivos li').length)+1; // variável que irá incrementar novas id's
function addMotivo() {
   var mot = document.getElementById("newMotivo").value;
   if (mot != "") {
      
      var antes = document.getElementById("motivos").innerHTML;
       antes += '<li id="listaMotivos'+ novoid +'"><b>'+ mot +'</b> <img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/delete.png" style="width: 1cm" onclick="deleteMot(\'' + novoid + '\');"></li>';
       document.getElementById("motivos").innerHTML = antes;
       document.getElementById("newMotivo").value = "";
       novoid++;
   }
   else {
       window.alert("Motivo inválido");
   }
}

function deleteMot(i){
  if (confirm("Tem a certeza que quer apagar?")) {
    document.getElementById("listaMotivos"+i).outerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```css
fieldset { border: none; }
label { display: block; cursor: pointer;}
.remove { color:black;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none; }
ul,li{
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="infor" style="clear: both;"><b>Motivos</b></div>
<div class="infor" style="clear: both; margin-top: 7px;">

<input type="text" id="newMotivo" placeholder="Ficar atraente"> 
<button onclick="addMotivo();" style="width: auto">Adicionar Motivo: </button>

</div>
<ul class="infor" id="motivos" style="clear: both; margin-top: 7px; color: #CC720E;">
   <li id="listaMotivos1">
      <b>Bem estar psicologico</b>
      <img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/1600/delete.png" style="width: 18px" onclick="deleteMot('1');" alt="" />
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: perfeito a resposta...muito obrigado

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com uma sugestão ainda melhor. Não deixe de marcar a resposta com ✓ para dar como solucionada. Abs!

Comment: Olá Evandro! A resposta não resolveu o problema? É importante marcar ✓ se resolveu para a pergunta não ficar aberta, ou então pode nos dizer o que faltou para que possamos melhorar a resposta.

Comment: desculpe @dvd ...agora fiz

Comment: pode me ajudar na nova pergunta que eu fiz?

Answer (score 1):

> Segue uma refatoração:

```js
var list = document.getElementById('motivos');
var lastid = 0;

function changeText2() {
    var firstname = document.getElementById('motivo').value;
    document.getElementById('anteriores').innerHTML = firstname;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstname));
    entry.setAttribute('id','item'+lastid);
    entry.setAttribute('data-name',firstname); //adicionou um atributo para facilitar o acesso ao nome
    var removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("remove"));
    removeButton.setAttribute('onClick','removeName("'+'item'+lastid+'")');
    entry.appendChild(removeButton);
    lastid+=1;
    list.appendChild(entry);
}


function removeName(itemid){
    var item = document.getElementById(itemid);
    list.removeChild(item);
}

function getNames(){
    var names = [];
    for(var i=0;i<list.children.length;i++){
        names.push(list.children[i].getAttribute("data-name"));//obter atributo definido anteriormente e adicionar ao array
    }
    return names;
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
Digite seu motivo:
<input type="text" id="motivo">
<br>
<p>Último motivo adicionado: <b id='anteriores'></b> 
</p>

<ol id="motivos"></ol>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Adicionar' />
<input type='button' onclick='alert(getNames())' value='Modal motivos' />
```

Comment: legal tambem, porem o dvd fez o que eu precisava so pra ajustar, mas vou positivar vc tb

Comment: @EvandroAguiar Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: eu que agradeço